# In Angularjs, how do I use ng-repeat, ng-model, and ng-click to dynamically change content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

As an example, I'm starting with html like this:

```
<div id="leftSide">

    <div class="item">

        <div class="editor">
            <ul class="choices">
                <li class="choice">This is  choice</li>
            </ul>
            <input class="myChoice" name="myChoice[]" />
        </div>

        <p class="theChoice"></p>

    </div>

    <div class="item">

        <div class="editor">
            <ul class="choices">
                <li class="choice">This is  choice</li>
            </ul>
            <input class="myChoice" name="myChoice[]" />
        </div>

        <p class="theChoice"></p>

    </div>

    <div class="item">

        <div class="editor">
            <ul class="choices">
                <li class="choice">This is  choice</li>
            </ul>
            <input class="myChoice" name="myChoice[]" />
        </div>

        <p class="theChoice"></p>

    </div>

</div>
```

The idea being, when I select an item i.e. `.choice` I want to add it to the input and the `.theChoice`. This way it displays what the user chose but they can edit it by typing the box.

I know how to do this with jquery. However, it will be a lot of overhead and I want to learn angular. I also know Angular can really clean this up.

I've used `ng-model` to mirror what a user types in the input box doing this:

```
<div id="leftSide">

    <div class="item">

        <div class="editor">
            <ul class="choices">
                <li class="choice">This is  choice</li>
            </ul>
            <input class="myChoice" name="myChoice[]" ng-model="choice1" />
        </div>

        <p class="theChoice">{{choice1}}</p>

    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I've used ng-repeat to loop out three of the `.item` divs:

```
<div id="leftSide" ng-controller="leftSide">

    <div class="item" ng-g-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">

        <div class="editor">
            <ul class="choices">
                <li class="choice">This is  choice</li>
            </ul>
            <input class="myChoice" name="myChoice[]" ng-model="choice1" />
        </div>

        <p class="theChoice">{{choice1}}</p>

    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

and js:

```
myApp.controller('leftSide',function($scope,$index){

    //three left boxes
    $scope.number = 3;
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }
    ...
});
```

The problem I have is (obviously) selecting the `.choice' is targeting all my`ng-model`s and not each that associate to its`.editor`. I'm certain I can use`$index`to handle this and/or maybe ng-click. I'm just a little lost on how to target the correct one based on the`.choice` I select.

Comment: How about adding selected choice as a property to `object` in `$scope` and adding it to hg-model like `obj.selectedchoice.$index` if required?

Comment: where are you targeting the .choice

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2hdeqb57/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny : I'm using some JS to get the text of the `li` and placing it in the `input` then running `$scope.$apply();`. This is where I think `ng-click` could clean things up.

Comment: can you edit the fiddle create a better demo... also how is the li's populated

Comment: @ArunPJohny : this is the issue [http://jsfiddle.net/2hdeqb57/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/2hdeqb57/2/)

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work, just not how to do it correctly. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the jQuery implementation, so I tried to solve your problem by pure AngularJS. You can run the snippet to check the answer:

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {

})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.number = 3;
  $scope.choice = [];
  $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);
  }

  $scope.choiceClick = function(i) {
    debugger;
    $scope.choice[i] = 'This is choice';
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="it in getNumber(number) track by $index">
    <div class="editor">
      <ul class="choices">
        <li class="choice" ng-click="choiceClick($index)">This is choice</li>
      </ul>
      <input class="myChoice" ng-model="choice[$index]" />
    </div>
    <p class="theChoice">{{choice[$index]}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I knew it could be done this way! I don't like the jQuery implementation either but it's what I know (lol). Reviewing this looks like it's exactly what I need. When I get home I'll apply the concept and test it. Funny thing is I was so close to doing it this way at one point :). If this works like I need I'll mark it.