# Change ng-click value dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app=angular.module('ang',[]);
app.controller('ctr',function($scope){

$scope.run=function(){alert("run")}
$scope.break=function(){alert("break")}

})
```

```css
.test{width:160px;height:30px;background-color:green;color:white}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>

    <div ng-app="ang" ng-controller='ctr'>
 
      <button class="test" ng-click="a?'run()':'break()'">click=calling...{{a?'run()':'break()'}}</button>
    <button ng-click="a=!a">click me</button>{{a}}

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here i want to dynamically change the value of ng-click based on a value using conditional statement,but it is not working as  expected.Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Angularjs, how do I use ng-repeat, ng-model, and ng-click to dynamically change content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271295/in-angularjs-how-do-i-use-ng-repeat-ng-model-and-ng-click-to-dynamically-chan)

Answer (score 4):

Change this line shown as below

Because it is already interpolated. You need not to mention `' '` again to call the scope function

```
<button class="test" ng-click="a?run():break()">click=calling...{{a?'run()':'break()'}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quote in the function

change this

```
{{a?'run()':'break()'}}
```

to this

```
{{a?run():break()}}
```

```js
var app=angular.module('ang',[]);
app.controller('ctr',function($scope){

$scope.run=function(){alert("run")}
$scope.break=function(){alert("break")}

})
```

```css
.test{width:160px;height:30px;background-color:green;color:white}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>

    <div ng-app="ang" ng-controller='ctr'>
 
      <div class="test" ng-click="a?'run()':'break()'">click=calling....{{a?run():break()}}</div>
    <button ng-click="a=!a">click me</button>{{a}}

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OHHH,Thank yOU verymuch :)

Comment: @Abhishek no problem make sure to check as answer if this helped :D